# Agregar datos de dos tablas en un mismo spinner (Java Android studio)

Tags: java, mysql, android, mvc, studio

necesito un poco de ayuda, lo que pasa es que necesito agregar datos de dos tablas diferentes en un mismo spinner, estoy manejando java con android studio.
Lo que necesito es que por ejemplo en el spinner que se muestra en la primer imagen aparecen esos dos elementos, ahi todo bien, pero lo que quiero es que tambien aparezcan los otros elementos que estan en otra tabla diferente (la de la segunda imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui se muestra la tabla en MYSQL y encerrado en rojo los elemntos que quiero mostrar en el mismo spinner.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la tercer imagen se hace la relacion de una tabla con la otra supongo que esa tabla debo agarrar el id para poder hacer el muestreo de esos datos en el spinner.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el modelo del spinner

```
public class ListModel {
    private int id;
    private int idResiduo;
    private String nombreResiduo;
    private String cantidadResiduo;
    private String unidadResiduo;

private Boolean selected = false;

public ListModel(int id, int idResiduo, String nombreResiduo, String cantidadResiduo, String unidadResiduo) {
    this.id = id;
    this.idResiduo = idResiduo;
    this.nombreResiduo = nombreResiduo;
    this.cantidadResiduo = cantidadResiduo;
    this.unidadResiduo = unidadResiduo;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombreResiduo() {
    return nombreResiduo;
}

public void setNombreResiduo(String nombreResiduo) {
    this.nombreResiduo = nombreResiduo;
}

public String getCantidadResiduo() {
    return cantidadResiduo;
}

public void setCantidadResiduo(String cantidadResiduo) {
    this.cantidadResiduo = cantidadResiduo;
}


public String getUnidadResiduo() {
    return unidadResiduo;
}

public void setUnidadResiduo(String unidadResiduo) {
    this.unidadResiduo = unidadResiduo;
}

public Boolean getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

}

Aqui es el controlador de ese modelo

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ListModel item);
}
//Declaración de Objetos
private Context context;
private ArrayList<ListModel> listModelList;
private ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListModel> listModelList, @NonNull ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener
        onItemClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listModelList = listModelList;
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

//Especificación del layout a utilizar
@NonNull
@Override
public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
    return new ListAdapter.ViewHolder(vista);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListModel listModel = listModelList.get(position);
    holder.view.setBackgroundColor(listModel.getSelected() ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
    holder.nombreResiduo.setText(listModel.getNombreResiduo());
    holder.cantidadResiduo.setText("Cantidad: " + listModel.getCantidadResiduo());
    holder.unidadResiduo.setText("Unidad: " + listModel.getUnidadResiduo());
    holder.bind(listModelList.get(position), onItemClickListener);

}


//Obtener el tamaño de la lista
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listModelList.size();
}

// Declaración de la clase ViewHolder para implementar datos a el elemento Card.
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView nombreResiduo, cantidadResiduo, unidadResiduo;
    private View view;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //cardViewResiduos = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardviewResiduos);
        view = itemView;
        nombreResiduo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreResiduoTxt);
        cantidadResiduo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidadResiduoTxt);
        unidadResiduo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unidadResiduo);
    }

    public void bind(final ListModel item, final ListAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.setSelected(!item.getSelected());
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(item.getSelected() ? Color.GRAY : Color.WHITE);
                listener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hola, no entiendo que es lo que tratas de realizar "supongo que esa tabla debo agarrar el id para poder hacer el muestreo de esos datos en el spinner.", simplemente envia los datos que deseas a tu Adapter.

Comment: ya vi que puedo, hacer, en otro script jalo los datos de mysql por medio de una conexion (archivo php) en esa conexion viene una consulta sql para mostrar e insertar datos, según lo que entendi solo es modificar esa consulta sql (por un join o cualquier otro) para que agarre la relacion entre las dos tablas (esa es la tabla de la segunda foto).

Comment: ` $sqlQuery = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO 137_dc_ordenresiduo (idorden, idresiduo, unidad, cantidad, cantidadreal, unidadreal) VALUES(" . $_POST['idorden'] . ", " . $_POST['idresiduo'] . ", '" . $_POST['unidad'] . "', CAST('"
        .  $_POST['cantidad'] . "' AS DOUBLE), CAST('" .  $_POST['cantidadreal'] . "' AS DOUBLE), '" .  $_POST['unidadreal'] . "')"); `

Comment: esa es la consulta que debo modificar

Comment: Si lo que tú quieres es que se añadan elementos a tu spinner desde otra tabla, debes modificar tu `select` no tu `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo.
Como mencione, la app agarra la informacion de consultas en php, asi que lo unico que hice fue modificar la consulta "**SELECT**" que es para mostrar elementos, y en esa consulta agregarle mostrar la union con las columnas de la otra tabla. Guarde los cambios y pude mostrar ambos elementos de ambas columnas en el spinner. Todo fue cuestión de saber manejar consultas en sql, aunque no es la mejor solución esa consulta ,me sirvió.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once("conexion.php");


  if (!isset($_POST['id']) ){
    exit('No ID!');
  }
    
  $sqlQuery = $conexion->prepare('SELECT rs.ID, rs.NombreResiduo FROM 137_dc_residuossitrasa AS rs UNION SELECT pr.ID, pr.Nombre FROM 137_dc_perfilresiduos AS pr WHERE IdCliente = ? AND (estatus = 1 OR  estatus = 2)');
  $sqlQuery->bind_param('s', $_POST['id']);
  $sqlQuery->execute();
  $sqlQuery->store_result();
  $sqlQuery->bind_result($ID, $NombreResiduo);

  if($sqlQuery->num_rows > 0){
     while($row = $sqlQuery->fetch()){
         echo $ID . "," . $NombreResiduo . "*";
     }
  }
  else{
     echo 'null';
  }

  $conexion->close();

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]